# CSS first and last child not related parent

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to make the first and last *.highlighted* elements red. The highlighted classes which are in the middle should be purple. Seeking dynamic CSS solution for any number or arrangement of .highlighted

```css
.highlighted {
  background: purple;
}

.highlighted:first-child,
.highlighted:last-child {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<td>
  <span>Test</span>
</td>
<td>
  <span>Test</span>
</td>
<td>
  <span class="highlighted">Test</span>
</td>
<td>
  <span class="highlighted">Test</span>
</td>
<td>
  <span class="highlighted">Test</span>
</td>
<td>
  <span class="highlighted">Test</span>
</td>
<td>
  <span>Test</span>
</td>
<td>
  <span>Test</span>
</td>
<td>
  <span>Test</span>
</td>
```

Comment: _"Could I solve this issue with only CSS?"_ - no. Not only can :first-child/:last-child and the class selector not be combined _that_ way (they can of course, but it means something different), you also only got _one_ single child per parent here.

Comment: Yes, I know that but I want to try my chance with asking. Thought maybe missing something :D I am using a library it's rendering like this. I should write JS for customizing. Thanks!

Comment: You can select the first one by `td:not(:has(.highlighted))+td:has(.highlighted) .highlighted`. But I don't think there is a way to select the last one by css. And firefox does not support `has()` .

Comment: @Shuo at least on my Edge/Chrome on Windows10 I have to remove the tds from your selector. I don't understand why as your solution ought I think to work, and mine shouldn't. Is there something specal about td elements that means they seem to be almost ignored? Or...?

Comment: I wrapped these tds by `<table>` and `<tr>` tags.

Comment: @shuo yes, I hadn't realised that a browser will ignore tds if not properly within trs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[I didn't understand why the snippet below, which leaves out the tds from the selectors, worked. I now do as @temaniafif has pointed out that the tds are ignored if not properly within trs etc. I leave this post here for a bit though to see if further info comes in.].

You can do this with pure CSS for those browsers which have implemented the CSS :has. [not true as far as I understand it now]

At the time of posting this, this is most of the major browsers except Firefox which will only implement :has if the user has set a flag.

What this snippet does is color all .highlight red. Then colors purple everything that is .highlighted and preceded by a .highlighted. Then colors the last one red again because it is not followed by a .highlighted.

```css
.highlighted {
  background: red;
}

.highlighted+.highlighted {
  background: purple;
}

.highlighted:has(+ :not(.highlighted)) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<td>
  <span>Test</span>
</td>
<td>
  <span>Test</span>
</td>
<td>
  <span class="highlighted">Test</span>
</td>
<td>
  <span class="highlighted">Test</span>
</td>
<td>
  <span class="highlighted">Test</span>
</td>
<td>
  <span class="highlighted">Test</span>
</td>
<td>
  <span>Test</span>
</td>
<td>
  <span>Test</span>
</td>
<td>
  <span>Test</span>
</td>
```

Comment: Works for me in Chromium but not Firefox even with the has flag enabled, on FF only the first is red with has enabled

Comment: td elements are only valid inside tr (that should be inside table) so the browser will remove them

Comment: @TemaniAfif thanks - that has stopped me worrying! Will experiment with putting in a proper table.

Comment: Firefox removes the trs but still whitespace nodes, maybe there's a discrepancy with how each engine handles those and +

Comment: @ZachJensz looks like this could be so. I realise my 'answer' isn't an answer but leave it up for a bit to see as I'm learning stuff from the comments.